# WebView error sound when typing (Swift, Cocoa)

Tags: html, swift, cocoa, webview

I recently made a simple macOS app that loads an html page form the bundle in a **WebKit WebView** (the new one, *not legacy*) but I noticed that when I type some keys in the page (not in an input box, I mean *body keypress handled using javascript*) an error sound is played. I was wondering if there is a solution for this problem.

I also might say that the html page **works perfectly** if I open it with Safari and there are no errors in the built-in inspector console as well as no error sound is played (which might tell us that the problem comes with something I'm missing in the application).

Here's my Swift code (App Delegate Obviously):

```
@IBOutlet weak var contentView: WebView!

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html", inDirectory: "HTML_Content")
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    contentView.mainFrame.load(request)

}
```

My HTML Code (Which works perfectly) [index.html]:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2 id="text"></h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript / jQuery Code [js/main.js]:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {

        var text = $('#text').text();

        if (e.which == 8) {
            if (text.length != 0) {
                text = text.slice(0, -1);
                $('#text').text(text);
            }
        } else if ('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 '.indexOf(
                    String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase()) != -1) {

            $('#text').text(text + String.fromCharCode(e.which));

        }

});
```

Can someone help me fix it?

Comment: Can you share your HTML?

Comment: @paulvs Added HTML, JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally understood why the application was giving me the error sound:

The **WebView** needs to *perform the key equivalent* on its content.

It actually couldn't perform it by default but I **forced it** using a custom class with this *override*, excluding the shortcut keys (or I wouldn't be able to use them):

**Swift 4:**

```
import WebKit

class WebViewController: WebView {

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        // Drawing code here.
    }

    override func performKeyEquivalent(with event: NSEvent) -> Bool {
        if event.modifierFlags.contains(.command) ||
           event.modifierFlags.contains(.control) ||
           event.modifierFlags.contains(.shift)   ||
           event.modifierFlags.contains(.option)  {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

}
```

Then I connected the custom class to the *xib element* using the element inspector's custom class property.

[image]

And, in the end, the sound was gone.